# Memory allocated with malloc does not persist outside function scope?

Tags: c, malloc

Hi,

I'm a bit new to C's malloc function, but from what I know it should store the value in the heap, so you can reference it with a pointer from outside the original scope. I created a test program that is supposed to do this but I keep getting the value 0, after running the program. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f1(int *b) {
    b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 5;
}

int main(void) {
    int *a;
    f1(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Yes! `a` is **passed by value** so the pointer `b` in function `f1` will be local.. 
either return `b`,

```
int *f1() {
    int * b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 5;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int * a;
    a = f1();
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    // keep it clean : 
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

or pass `a`'s address

```
int f1(int ** b) {
    *b = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    **b = 5;
}

int main() {
    int * a;
    f1(&a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    // keep it clean : 
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're misunderstanding a fundamental part of how C works - namely that it is a 'pass-by-value' language.  In order for `main()` to know about the memory you allocated, you have to get it back out.  The following code will do you what you want:

```
int f1(int **b)
{
    *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **b = 5;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *a;
    f1(&a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

There are a couple differences between this code and yours; first, the signature of `f1()` has changed, so that it can return the result of the `malloc()` call in the passed in pointer.  Next, the call to `f1()` has been changed to pass the address of `a` rather than `a` itself - important if you want it to be 'filled-in' by `f1()`, so to speak.  Finally, the `printf()` in `main()` has been changed to print out the pointed-to value rather than the pointer itself.

Comment: I'm at a loss why everyone has jumped straight to using a pointer-to-a-pointer - that's hardly the best way to explain how to do this to someone who's having trouble with a more fundamental part of the language.  Why not just return the pointer from `f1()`?

Comment: @caf, yes! that's simple for a beginner to understand.!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback everyone! My code works now. 
I can't have the function return the pointer, because the function in my actual project it is already returning something else..

Thanks again!

Comment: @caf, this is a fundamental of the C language, why *wouldn't* explaining the pointer-to-a-pointer concept be useful here?

Comment: I just think it adds needless complication to the explanation, which at heart is that the pointer value needs to somehow be returned to the higher scope.  Anyway, this equine is now deceased - there is no sense flogging it any further.

Comment: Hi @Mar, may I ask why you did not add in the free(a)?

Answer (score 6):

The memory itself persists, but it leaks because you're not providing the allocated pointer to the caller.  Also, you're printing `a` when you should be printing `*a`.  Finally, you're not returning an int from `f1`.

Try:

```
void f1(int **b) {
 *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
 **b = 5;
}

int main() {
 int *a;
 f1(&a);
 printf("%d\n", *a);
 free(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets suppose you assign a value of `NULL` to a before you call function `f1`. Now the way f1 is defined it takes its argument(pointer to an `int`) by value. That is `b` will be another variable of type `int *` which will be a ***copy*** of `a`. So `b` too will have a value of `NULL`. Now in `f1` you change the value by `b` by assigning it the address of memory allocated dynamically using `malloc`. Lets say that memory address is `0x123`. As a result of this assignment, `b` has changed its value from `NULL` to `0x123` but `a`(in `main`) continues to hold `NULL`, because changing b will not change `a`, as they are two separate variables. As a result of this when you return from function `f1` a will remain unchanged.

There are 2 ways to solve this. One you can make the function `f1` return the value of the changed `b` and then assign it back to a in `main` and two, you can pass the a by address so that any changes made in `f1` will affect a in `main` too.

```
// f1 now returns the value of b.
int* f1() {
 int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *b = 5;
 return b;
}

int main() {
 int *a = NULL;
 a = f1(); // assign the return value of f1 to a.
 printf("%d\n", *a); // prints 5...not its *a not just a.
 return 0;
}
```

.

```
// f1 now takes the address of a. 
void f1(int **b) {
 *b = malloc(sizeof(int)); // you are actually altering a indirectly.
 **b = 5; 
}

int main() {
 int *a = NULL;
 f1(&a); // now pass the address of a to f1.
 printf("%d\n", *a); // prints 5...not its *a not just a.
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually not related to malloc, but rather the fact that you're passing the value the pointer currently holds, rather than the address of it.  Try the following:

```
int f1(int ** b) {
    *b = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    **b = 5;
}

int main() {
    int * a;
    f1(&a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

By passing the pointer value as you were, there was no way for the value malloc created to be stored into the pointer.

Comment: This is again pass by value. u r passing the address of a by value. **There is no pass by reference in C**

Comment: Fair enough.  Updated to be more accurate in C.

Answer (score 0):

The address `int *b` is deleted when the function return. To save it, **you need to use a pointer of a pointer**

```
int f1(int ** b) {
   *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
   **b = 5;
}
```