# Using char ** in function, that we could malloc memory for char * that is passed to her

Tags: c, pointers

Read:

- [Scope of malloc used in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629082/scope-of-malloc-used-in-a-function)
- [Memory allocated with malloc does not persist outside function scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513218/memory-allocated-with-malloc-does-not-persist-outside-function-scope)

and other questions on SO related to this question
and other on world wide web, so continue reading...

Since soon, i figure, i never `alloc` like this memory for `char *`, but I thought it may work:

```
void _alloc(char *line)
         *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFSIZE);
```

Ignore error handler in `_alloc` and `main`. The main thing is `SEGFAULT` on section like this:

```
 main()
   {
       char *text, *start;
       _alloc(text);
       start = text;
       // add contents in text briefly
       *text++ = 'd'; *text = '\0';  // SEGFAULT
       fprintf(stdout, "%s", start);
   }
```

I had a picture that function _alloc working something like this:

```
    main()
   {
     char *text;
     /// function _alloc:
     char *tmp = text;
     *tmp  = malloc ( sizeof(char) * BUFSIZE);
     /// end
   }
```

And...
When i tried this, it give me **warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast and SEGF**.
My picture about it , is:

```
tmp = text; // tmp point at address of line
 *tmp = malloc(...); // tmp change to what point line...
```

And i saw that i need in _alloc( char **) , and can't figure how it works with **. I tried to manipulate with array[][], i know it. But can't get picture, why it need to be char **?
Here is part of answer:

> Here, `line` is a local variable within `_alloc` . Pointers are passed by
>   value in C, so a receives a copy of the pointer in main when you do
>   `_alloc(text);`  < answer user nos (modified with my name of variables) on [Scope of malloc used in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629082/scope-of-malloc-used-in-a-function)

P.S. i know that is simpler to write function like this `char *_alloc();`

Comment: But you're not passing a `char **` to the `_alloc` function.

Comment: `void _alloc(char **line);` and `char *text; _alloc(&text);`?

Comment: Sorry for this, i change now. I changed name of variables because, it wasn't so readable, and forget to change for all, mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simple example, with an int.

Suppose we have the functions :

```
void foo(int n)
{
    n = 3;
}

int main(void)
{
   int number = 5;
   foo(number);
}
```

I think you will agree that `number` is not modified after `foo(number)`. This is because `n` is only a copy of `number`, a local variable which is destroyed after `foo` exited.

This is the reason why we use pointers. But a pointer is a variable, and it's exactly the same thing. Look at this example :

```
void bar(int *n)
{
   *n = 3;
   int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *temp = 6;
   n = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int number = 5;
    int *number_p = &number;
    bar(number_p);
}
```

Here, `number = 3` after `bar(number_p)`, because we pass to `bar` the adress of our integer. However, the adress itself is a copy of the original pointer.
So, the instruction `n = temp;` doesn't do anything to `number_p`, as n is just a local variable.

That's why we need to use a pointer to a pointer.

With the following example, you can modify the original pointer inside the `foo` function :

```
void foo(int **n)
{
    **n = 3;
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *temp = 6;
    *n = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int number = 5;
    int *number_p = &number;
    foo(&number_p); //We pass the adress of the pointer number_p
}
```

After `foo(&number_p)`, `number` is 3, and `number_p` is a pointer to `temp`, because we were able to modify the adress itself in `foo`.

In your example, you need to modify the pointer in the `_alloc` function, so the signature should be

```
void _alloc(char **line)
```

and the pointer should be modified using

```
*line = malloc(...);
```

Also, `_alloc` should be called like this

```
char* s;
_alloc(&s);
```

Sorry for my bad english, I did the best in order to be clear.

Comment: Is there memory leaks when void bar(int *n) do work with temp. Temp destroy?, but does that memory whom is alloced ( can consider to be leak)?

Comment: @RadijatoR Yes, there is a memory leak. `temp` is allocated on the stack, so it is destroyed at the end of `bar`, but *temp is still on the heap. In the second example, you need to ˋfree(temp)` at the end of ˋbarˋ. In the third example, you need to ˋfree(number_p)` at the end of ˋmain`. My code was just illustrative. :)

Comment: I accept you answer, because there is something, that i didn't know, but i doesn't have picture yet, about char **, you just wrote "and the pointer should be modified using" .

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
void _alloc(char **line){
     *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFSIZE);
}
```

use like this:

```
/* ... */
char *buf;
_alloc(&buf);
```

`buf` is a pointer. You get a pointer to it with `&buf`, then pass it to `_alloc`, which dereferences the pointer-to-pointer, getting at `buf`'s value, and changes it to point to newly allocated memory.

C is strictly pass-by-value, so pointers are not treated differently from variables. I.e., to understand this, you could consider the analogy to the following code:

```
void changeValue(char *chr){
     *chr = 'a';
}
```

(used like this:)

```
/* ... */
char buf;
changeValue(&buf);
```

Comment: Man, i ask why need char **, i read this what u write in annexed links.

Comment: Yes it helps. But. Like you post your answer, you in _alloc set, *line = malloc... , so what is **line mind? why is there two *?

Comment: @RadijatoR: it's simple. Declaring a variable with an `*` makes it a pointer of some type. For example, `int *a` is a pointer to int. Note that a pointer (`int *`) is also a type in itself. That means you can create a pointer to an object of this type, too. Simply by adding another `*`, like this: `char **a`. Here, `a` is a *pointer to a pointer to char* (i.e. you can say it is the address of the memory where the address of `a` is stored). This is C's pointer arithmetics, and they may be a bit hard to grasp =)